# WebAPI 2 return types that don't break the help documentation website

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to use the (apparently preferred) IHttpActionResult return type for my API methods without breaking the super handy help documentation?  When I return
`List<T>` 
from my method, I get very descriptive help documentation.  When I return IHttpActionResult, I get useless help documentation.  Why give us such a cool toy and then suggest that we use something that breaks the toy?  Am I missing a great resource for how to use the documentation website together with the MS preferred style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to append [ResponseTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to your action methods which specifies the expected return type when using `HttpResponseMessage` or `IHttpActionResult`. This should then be picked up by [ApiExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apiexplorer(v=vs.118).aspx) when it generates the documentation.

From the website:

> Use this to specify the entity type returned by an action when the declared return type is HttpResponseMessage or IHttpActionResult. The ResponseType will be read by ApiExplorer when generating ApiDescription.

*If you are using another API to generate the documentation you should check if they support it or include it in the question and maybe someone here knows off hand.*

Comment: Ahhh, so I *was* missing the great resource for how to use the documentation website.  I was going about it in the wrong direction, looking for documentation on the website when I should have dug into what actually creates the site.  Thanks Igor!